# Editable an executable python snippet in HTML page to be sent to python server

Tags: javascript, python, websocket

I'm building a vanilla web socket client (Javascript) - server(Python).
The page that hosts the websocket client shows a Python script like the following

```
<pre id="mainPyScript" contenteditable="true">
def tellMeFour():
 return 5

tellMeFour()
</pre>
```

A visitor is invited to correct the snippet, which is then sent via to the python websocket server and injected into the `exec` function to make sure that the user corrected the mistake (this is a small and local exercise, no security concerns).

The question is: how do I make sure that the "what you see" formatting in the  tag is respected, so that indentation is preserved when passing this to `exec`?

Comment: "this is a small and local exercise, no security concerns" What if the user inputs malicious code while "fixing the code?" Also, why not just send the `.innerHTML` property or something of the like? By sending the exact string, the indentation will be preserved.

Comment: i think there is good explantion here http://lucumr.pocoo.org/2011/2/1/exec-in-python/